# utilizing beforeMove/afterMove without a binding?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I need to detect when items are moved in an [observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html). In my current version (2.1.0) I accomplish this by calling `setTimeout` on all delete events and waiting to see if an add event follows immediately on its heels:

```
  var delayed = [];
  var key; /* obtained by comparing original observableArray with updated list and iterating all differences */

  if( /** record exists in original list but not new list ) {
     // it was deleted, we don't immediately fire a notification (it may get re-inserted in a moment)
     delayed[key] = setTimeout(function() { sendDeleteNotification(key); }, 0);
  }
  else if( /** record exists in new list but not original */ ) {
     if( delayed[key] ) { 
        // it was deleted and immediately re-added (it's a move)
        clearTimeout(delayed[key]); 
        sendMoveNotification( key );
     }
     else {
        // it was added
        sendAddedNotification( key );
     }
  }
```

In knockout 2.2, I see [new events for beforeMove and afterMove](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/259). However, I can't find any means to utilize them programmatically.

The end goal is to be able to mirror client changes in the database immediately, but not show an add/delete in place of a move event. A record moved up or down in the list shouldn't be marked as deleted and then newly added.

Can the new beforeMove/afterMove bindings be utilized in JavaScript directly (e.g. event model?) to improve this?

Cheers,

Comment: Have you read the [updated documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)? Look for the  *Post-processing or animating the generated DOM elements* section. It documents the usage of the `beforeMove/afterMove` callbacks.

Comment: @Tyrsius I've added some of my motivations, hopefully that will narrow the question; I didn't realize it was nebulous.

Comment: @nemesv ah knockout docs; I didn't think to check in foreach although in hindsight it seems more obvious. Really I'm trying to see these from JavaScript and not from the html binding though. Also, your answer is just such a thing and deserves some votes!

Comment: Do you mean reflected in the db immediately? If not, then aren't you just sending back the whole list to the server at the end of client editing?

Comment: Yes, immediately, I'm writing a lib to help our app with real-item (push) updates and collaboration; thanks for the great questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I utilized was based on [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166982/determine-which-element-was-added-or-removed-with-a-knockoutjs-observablearray) and [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/Jq3ru/).

The `beforeMove` and `afterMove` functions can be accessed by a simple subscription:

```
var obs = ko.observableArray();
obs.subscribe(function( arrayOfValues ) {
   console.log('moving', arrayOfValues);
}, undefined, 'beforeMove');

obs.subscribe(function( arrayOfValues ) {
   console.log('moved', arrayOfValues);
}, undefined, 'afterMove');
```

However, it turns out this wasn't particularly useful as it returns all the elements in the array that change index. For instance, if I delete a record from the list, I get a moved event for every record after the deleted one.

So I'll be sticking with the timeout until I find something better.