# How does KnockoutJS know when an item is 'moved' in an array?

Tags: knockout.js

In the [foreach documentation section about post-processing](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements), it is said that one can:

> use any of the afterRender/afterAdd/beforeRemove/beforeMove/afterMove callback

When I do:

```
var myArray = ko.observableArray([complexObj, complexObj, complexObj]);
// move the second item to the first position
myArray.splice(0, 0, myArray().splice(1, 1)[0]);
```

I first *remove* 1 item, then *add*  it back, in other words I *move* it. How can Knockout distinguish which callback to fire when (or does it fire all 3)?
How does Knockout distinguish between an array item that has been moved and one that is newly added but with exactly the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform two operations on the array, Knockout sees them as separate and will call the `beforeRemove` and `afterAdd` callbacks. To get the *move* callbacks to fire, Knockout will need to see both changes simultaneously. One way to accomplish this is to use the `rateLimit` extender on the observable array:

```
var myArray = ko.observableArray([obj1, obj2, obj3]).extend({rateLimit: 0});

// move the second item to the first position
myArray.splice(0, 0, myArray.splice(1, 1)[0]);
```

In your question, the inner `splice` is performed against the underlying array directly instead of the observable array because it uses `myArray().splice()`. So Knockout actually only sees the operation performed by the outer splice, by which time both have been completed.

Knockout knows that items are moved because it compares the current contents of the array to its previous contents using a version of the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question very well. I think this should be stated somewhere in the documentation so that we know when/why to update the underlying array vs. using Knockout's array methods.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391711/utilizing-beforemove-aftermove-without-a-binding#13500059), the `*move` callbacks will fire for every record whose index changes. That means when you remove one, all the ones after it would have their callbacks fired. Then when you insert, they'd fire again. The two `splice`s are separate operations on the observableArray; it has no way of noticing that you're using them together.