# How to prevent computed() from firing when its array value doesn't change

Tags: knockout-2.0

This seems like a question that should have been answered already, but I haven't been able to find any discussion of this.

I have an array of items, some of which may be selected:

```
function Item(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.selected = ko.observable(false);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.items = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.selected = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function (item) {
            return item.selected();
        });
    }, this);
}
```

Since `viewmodel.selected()` depends on `viewmodel.items()`, whenever I add a new object to `items` the `selected` observable also changes, even if the added item is not selected. How do I prevent `this.selected()` from updating if no new items are actually selected?

Comment: Why is it a problem that the selected changes every time when the items changes?

Comment: Because it causes a query to be run on the server to respond to the selection, but in fact there was no selection.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can achieve this with a pure ko.computed solution.
Maybe you could subscribe to your "items" changes. When one item is added, you check if it is selected and push it to another observableArray if it is.

See the first answer to this question : [Determine which element was added or removed with a Knockoutjs ObservableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166982/determine-which-element-was-added-or-removed-with-a-knockoutjs-observablearray)
It would allow you to subscribe to specific changes on your "items" (item added or deleted).