# UI not update after removing item from observableArray with jquery.dataTables

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, mvc.jquery.datatables

I am using `jquery.dataTables` and `knockout js` to bind data to a table.

After removing an item from the `observableArray`, the UI does not update. Because I bind data to `jquery.Datatable` it is possible to re-init the table; so I re-init the table by calling the `TableManaged.init();` method but it is generating warning `cannot reinitialise datatable`.

Below is my code.

```js
function PatientVM(vm) {
  self.MDSPatientId = ko.observable(vm.MDSPatientId());
  self.PatientNumber = ko.observable(vm.PatientNumber());
  self.PrescribingDay = ko.observable(vm.PrescribingDay());
  self.OneWeekItems = ko.observable(vm.OneWeekItems());
  self.DeliveryDay = ko.observable(vm.DeliveryDay());
  self.IsActive = ko.observable(vm.IsActive());
  self.WeekColor = ko.observable(vm.WeekColor());
  self.PatientName = ko.observable(vm.PatientName());
  self.FullAddress = ko.observable(vm.FullAddress());
}

function Patients(vm) {
  var self = this;
  self.PatientList = ko.observableArray();

  if (vm.PatientList() != null) {
    for (i = 0; i < vm.PatientList().length; i++) {
      var p = new PatientVM(vm.PatientList()[i]);
      self.PatientList.push(p);
    }
  }

  self.DeletePatient = function(patient) {
    var result = confirm("Want to delete?");
    if (result) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("DeleteMDSPatient", "Patient")',
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          'MDSPatientId': patient.MDSPatientId()
        },
        success: function(response) {
          if (response.Result == 3) {
            self.PatientList.remove(patient);
            ShowToastMessage("Patient has been deleted successfully", "Success", true);
          }
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {}
      });
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new Patients(ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)))));
  App.init();
  TableManaged.init();
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_3" style="line-height:22px;table-layout:fixed;overflow-x:hidden;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:#348fe2">
      <th style="width:5%;text-align:center">
        <span class="showellipses">Active Patient</span>
      </th>
      <th style="width:10%"><span>Name</span>
      </th>
      <th style="width:20%"><span class="showellipses">Address</span>
      </th>
      <th style="width:10%"><span class="showellipses">PrescribingDay</span>
      </th>
      <th style="width:5%"><span class="showellipses">No. of items in four week</span>
      </th>
      <th style="width:10%"><span class="showellipses">Assembly Week</span>
      </th>
      <th style="width:10%"><span>Delivery Day</span>
      </th>
      <th style="width:5%">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:PatientList">
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:IsActive, click:ChangePatientStatus" class="checkboxes" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="showellipses" data-bind="text:PatientName"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="showellipses" data-bind="text:FullAddress"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="text:PrescribingDay"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="center">
        <span data-bind="text:OneWeekItems"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="text:WeekColor"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="text:DeliveryDay"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a title="Edit" style="text-decoration:none" class="fa fa-edit" data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action(" PatientView ", "Patient ")?MDSPatientId=' + MDSPatientId()}"></a>&nbsp;|
        <a title="Delete" style="text-decoration:none" class="fa fa-trash-o" data-bind="click:$parent.DeletePatient"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Think *very* hard if you really want to use knockout to render your table. DataTables has its own very powerful table rendering engine and you absolutely should use it. DataTables and knockout functionality heavily overlap and compete in this case, and it's not easy to make them play nice with each other. It would be wise to use only one of the libraries for this part of your page, and using only DataTables will in the end be a lot easier than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from their docs [link](https://datatables.net/dev/knockout/).

You need an extra step to notify the jquery plugin to update the table.
Basically you need to subscribe to the array changes and invalidate the row deleted.
They suggest using a helper for subscribing to the observable array like this:

```
// Helper function so we know what has changed
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166982
ko.observableArray.fn.subscribeArrayChanged = function(addCallback, deleteCallback) {
    var previousValue = undefined;
    this.subscribe(function(_previousValue) {
        previousValue = _previousValue.slice(0);
    }, undefined, 'beforeChange');
    this.subscribe(function(latestValue) {
        var editScript = ko.utils.compareArrays(previousValue, latestValue);
        for (var i = 0, j = editScript.length; i < j; i++) {
            switch (editScript[i].status) {
                case "retained":
                    break;
                case "deleted":
                    if (deleteCallback)
                        deleteCallback(editScript[i].value);
                    break;
                case "added":
                    if (addCallback)
                        addCallback(editScript[i].value);
                    break;
            }
        }
        previousValue = undefined;
    });
};
```

And then you need to subscribe and act to the array changes:

```
self.PatientList.subscribeArrayChanged(
        function ( addedItem ) {
            dt.row.add( addedItem ).draw();
        },
        function ( deletedItem ) {
            var rowIdx = dt.column( 0 ).data().indexOf( deletedItem.id );
            dt.row( rowIdx ).remove().draw();
        }
    );
```

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/yeM3D0pEphSIDOkzeVCp?p=preview) with the full example.

Comment: This could be a good answer for the question, however links tend to get broken over time. It would be good if you considered copy-pasting the relevant parts of the code into your answer. Thanks.

Comment: The answer you link to is very old and has since been superseded by [knockout's native array change notifications](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/10/08/knockout-3-0-release-candidate-available/#array-change-subscriptions) (available since version 3.0). The `subscribeArrayChanged` function is superfluous.